# Is there a way of convincing Git to merge changes between files, rather than branches?

Tags: git

Say I have a file, `foo.txt`.  I decide I want a `bar.txt`, which is like `foo.txt`, but with some major changes to one part of it.

If I make a branch `bar`, and make those changes there (probably including a rename), I can the merge the changes to `foo.txt` into `bar.txt` with `git merge.

If, on the other hand, I just copy the file such that `foo` and `bar` are different files in the same branch, is there a way of keeping [certain] changes synchronized between them?

The "correct" choice is to make the code more modular, to remove the duplicate code -- but presuming that isn't an available solution, is there a way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You can fake something by using an updating tag and a script to manually diff/patch though.

Comment: This is just diffing and patching, any programmer's editor should be able to selectively apply diff hunks.  run vim as `vimdiff file1 file2` and it'll start up in that mode.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**git merge-file**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file)

```
git merge-file <current-file> <base-file> <other-file>
```

> git merge-file incorporates all changes that lead from the
>   <base-file> to <other-file> into <current-file>. The
>   result ordinarily goes into <current-file>. git merge-file is
>   useful for combining separate changes to an original. Suppose
>   <base-file> is the original, and both <current-file> and
>   <other-file> are modifications of <base-file>, then git
>   merge-file combines both changes.

In your case you can create an empty and the do a git merge-file,

```
git merge-file foo.txt empty.txt bar.txt
```

`foo.txt` is your merged file

Comment: The result of `<base-file> == <current-file>` would be that after the merge `<current-file> == <other-file>`: It would replay the difference between `<base-file>` and `<other-file>` on `<base-file>`, recreating `<other-file>`.

Comment: using an empty file as `<base-file>` should do it.

Comment: That will give one big merge conflict, leaving you essentially in the same place where you started...

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible, *unless you have a base version of your file before the diverged*.

Git always uses three file states in a merge: a base file C, a version A and a version B. It then effectively adds the diffs between C and A, and C and B, replaying them both on file C. Unless you have three *different* input files, the output will always be either file A or file B without any changes.